# Detecting ScrollOffset in ScrollView inside ViewController held within UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I hava a `UIPageViewController` that holds an array of `ContentUIViewController`, these have scrollviews in them.

When the scrollview scrolls I want to recognise this in the view controller that is the parent of the `UIPageViewController` (added as child)

What would be the best route to achieve this? as currently I tried delegating the `didScroll` back to the viewmodel for the `ContentUIViewController` then feeding that into the parent of the `UIPageViewController` to adjust header height that I want to collapse, but it doesn't work well / is very hacky

Is there a way to read delegate output in the a child vc to the parent vc without feeding it back through viewmodels? This is proving tricky due to the array nature of the `UIPageViewController` rather than a single child VC.

Updated:

```
private func generateContentControllers() -> [UIViewController] {
    var viewControllers: [UIViewController] = []
        viewControllers.append(ScrollableContentViewController(contentViews: infoViews))
        viewControllers.append(reviewsVC)
        viewControllers.append(ScrollableContentViewController(contentViews: helpViews))
    }
    return viewControllers
}
```

Provided via

```
var scrollingViewControllers: [UIViewController] { get }
```

Added with

```
    if let firstViewController = self.viewModel.scrollingViewControllers.first {
        pagingController.setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: You can set a closure to pageViewController and call that in didScroll method

Comment: Also add the relevant code.

Comment: that would only let if callback to the viewmodel that created it, not the parent VC, theres too much code involved in too many places to provide it all in the question

Comment: Added the approach as an answer. See if you can relate with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get that working.

**1.** Create a `handler` in `ContentUIViewController` that will be called in `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` method for each `contentOffset` change.

```
class ContentUIViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var handler: ((CGPoint)->())?

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        handler?(scrollView.contentOffset)
    }
}
```

**2.** In `ParentVC`, create an instance of `UIPageViewController` and add it as a `child` to it. I think you did that already.

What you need to do next is create an `array` of `ContentUIViewController` and for each instance set the `handler` that we created earlier.

This `handler` will be called every time the `scrollView` is scrolled in that particular `ContentUIViewController`. We'll get the `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` here. Call `updateHeaderHeight(for:)` with the obtained `contentOffset` to adjust the `header` height.

```
class ViewModel {
    private func generateContentControllers() -> [ContentUIViewController] {
        var viewControllers: [ContentUIViewController] = []
        //add your code here....
        return viewControllers
    }

    lazy var scrollingViewControllers: [ContentUIViewController] = {
        return self.generateContentControllers()
    }()
}

class ParentVC: UIViewController {
    let viewModel = ViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewModel.scrollingViewControllers.forEach {
            $0.handler = {(offset) in
                self.updateHeaderHeight(for: offset)
            }
        }
    }

    func updateHeaderHeight(for offset: CGPoint) {
        //add the code to adjust header height here...
    }

    //add rest of the code for pageViewController here....
}
```

Comment: i did try this setup initially, the issue here is that the ContentUIViewController are created in the viewmodel of ParentVC and not in ParentVC its self, so its abstracted further back, the callback wouldnt be at the ParentVC scope and the View Model has no visibility of ParentVC specifically it can only provide a value in its protocol

Comment: The handler could be set in the ViewModel as well. And add the relevant code please.

Comment: ive updated the OP to show creation, the VM property passed and how its added in the parent VC, as you can see if you add the handler in the VM, itll parse back but then you cant get that value into the parentVC to use if effectively at that scope

Comment: Updated the code as per your requirement. Also, you need to write that much code to pass the contentOffset back the view hierarchy either using delegate or closures. There is no other way.

Comment: thanks i managed to get it working by working off your approach, the key was the forEach and adding the callback in the parent VC, thanks!